# Create folders with name which taken from txt file in another directory

Tags: windows, file, cmd

I have a problem with creating folders (with for loop) in which names are taken from txt file , if the folder has not been created(some names have spaces) write down the name of the file which has not been created in another txt file.

Here I have for loop to create folders with custom names from txt file:

```
for /F %i in (file.txt) do md %i
```

Comment: It would help others to answer if you detailed the problems you're having with the call command.  What syntax did you use?  What error or result did you get?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set list=C:\your_list.txt
set location=C:\your_location


for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (%list%) do (
    md "%location%\%%G"
    if errorlevel 1 (echo Error creating folder : %location%\%%G >> Error.txt)
)
```

Comment: That is working, but in my case I need to open(call) file which is one level lower in directory and I didn't have it in the folder where I'm going to create folders and write error.txt

Comment: For example, my list.txt is placed in F:\Fld\list.txt but I need to create folders from list.txt in F:\Fld\Fld1

Comment: You can put the path by editing in the second line here `md "F:\Fld\Fld1\%%G"`